# Excel VBA duplicate rows and increase date

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have an excel sheet with 170 employees and I need to duplicate those rows to have one row per employee per day of the month.

I managed to use VBA to duplicate the rows but it is a straight copy of the date and I want it to increase so that everyone has a row for each unique date of month. What I am using so far:

```
Sub TimesThirty()
Dim LR As Long:     LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim BR As Long:     BR = LR * 31

Rows("1:" & LR).Copy Rows(LR + 1 & ":" & BR)
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=[A1], Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

End Sub
```

Thanks for any assistance.

[example of columns set up:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWV2m.png)

Comment: Include your code and a little more description to improve your question.

Comment: To make it easier to understand, show some example data and also example data of the expected outcome.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. If you need help implementing this, feel free to ask:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TimesThirty()
    Dim LR As Long:     LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim BR As Long:     BR = LR * Day(Application.EoMonth(Date, 1)) 'this way it will do it for the number of days of the current month
    Dim arrData As Variant, ws As Worksheet, x As Integer, i As Long, h As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Name") 'change name for the name of your sheet

    With ws
        x = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last column on your sheet
        arrData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(BR, x)).Value

        'A loop through the array to copy the values except the Date which will go adding a day each loop
        For i = 1 To LR 'for every worker
            For h = 1 To Day(Application.EoMonth(Date, 1)) 'for every day of the month
                For x = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2) 'for every column
                    If x = 1 Then 'I'm assuming the Date is on the column 1, else change the value of x
                        arrData(LR + h, x) = DateSerial(Year(arrData(i, x)), Month(arrData(i, x)), h) 'Year, Month, Day
                    Else
                        arrData(LR + h, x) = arrData(i, x) 'copy the same value
                    End If
                Next x
            Next h
        Next i

        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(BR, x)).Value = arrData 'Paste the array back to the sheet

    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Damian, I am getting an error 'subscript out of range' so still trying to figure out what I am doing wrong (I am only a beginner).

Comment: This code was by just guessing... We could find out what's wrong if you give some screens of your data (where we can see columns and rows)